# pinterest share count function in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, pinterest

I have a working facebook sharecounter. But I am having difficulty getting it to work the same way for pinterest.

Here is my function:

```
    //sharecount fo pinterest
function get_pins() {
    $pin_results = file_get_contents('http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url='. get_permalink());
    $pin_array = json_decode($pin_results, true);
    $pin_count =  $pin_array['count'];
    return ($pin_count ) ? $pin_count : "0";
}
```

Here is the code on wordpress theme file for the share button:

```
<span class="social_count"><?php echo get_pins(); ?></span>
```

Always returning 0.

if I test out the api with url in browser this is the json return:

receiveCount({"url":"http://example.com/2015/05/get-moving-for-mindstrong-lets-stop-the-stigma/","count":1})

here are the results of echoing $pin_results:

receiveCount({"url":"http://example.com/2015/05/get-moving-for-mindstrong-lets-stop-the-stigma/","count":2})

Comment: Pinterest may block web hosts' IP ranges from accessing that API, as it's not supposed to be used server-side like this. See if `$pin_results` contains an error message of some sort.

Comment: here are the results of echoing $pin_results:              receiveCount({"url":"http://example.com/2015/05/get-moving-for-mindstrong-lets-stop-the-stigma/","count":2})

Comment: Is it because of the "receiveCount( ) that encompasses the Json?

Comment: Yep, that's not JSON. That's JSONP. Please see the dupe question for code to parse it.

Comment: awesome thanks. Works with that function

Answer (score 1):

You send `get_permalink()` to the API and not `$url`. Outside of the loop, without any parameter, `get_permalink` act like this:

> Note that when used outside The Loop on a posts page (index, archive,
>   etc.) without the ID parameter, it will return the URL of the last
>   post in The Loop, not the permalink for the current page

Which is why it returns 0 - you probably send a random url to the API.

Comment: Yep you are right. However I update the code to reflect the same way the facebook code is working properly and I am still getting 0. I edited my question to show the way I update it.